# Manually pass additional data during partial model update

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have to pass user to different fields depending on the requested data. In case the instance was "rejected" I need to pass `rejected = True` and the user as `rejected_by = request.user` how to change those values manually since I use `partial_update`. I have tried to do this by passing additional data to `serializer_class` but this seems to not work.

```
class AcceptRejectCoreWord(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = WordCoreModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AcceptRejectCoreWordSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = get_user_model().objects.get(email=request.user)
        if not user.groups.filter(name="Moderator").exists():
            return Response({
                'error': 'Only moderators have permissions to view this endpoint'},
                status=status.HTTP_403_BAD_REQUEST)

        if request.data['rejected']:
            reject_reason = request.data['rejection_reason']
            if not reject_reason:
                return Response({
                    'error': 'Rejection reason is required'},
                    status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            self.serializer_class(accepted=False, accepted_dy=None, rejected=True, rejected_by=user, modified_by=user,
                                  publishing_status='rejected')
        if request.data['accepted']:
            self.serializer_class(rejected=False, rejected_by=None, accepted=True, accepted_dy=user, modified_by=user,
                                  publishing_status='published')

        return self.partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

My serializer class contains this fields but I don't know how to update them in case of using `partial_update` method.

```
class AcceptRejectCoreWordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    part_of_speech_type = CoreWordSpeechPartDescriptionSerializer(
        many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = WordCoreModel
        fields = ['id', 'word_core', 'word_russian_typed',
                  'word_english_typed', 'part_of_speech_type', 'uncensored_word', 'modified_by', 'publishing_status',
                  'accepted', 'accepted_by', 'rejected', 'rejected_by', 'rejection_reason']
        extra_kwargs = {'id': {'read_only': False}}

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        word_descriptions = validated_data.pop('part_of_speech_type')
        core_word = WordCoreModel.objects.get(id=validated_data['id'])
        for word_description in word_descriptions:
            CoreWordSpeechPartDescription.objects.update(
                word=core_word, **word_description)
        return core_word
```

The implementaion above gives me error: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'accepted'`, which raises on the following line: `self.serializer_class(accepted=False, accepted_dy=None, rejected=True, rejected_by=user, modified_by=user, publishing_status='rejected')`

Comment: You initialise a Serializer with an object or `data` dictionary, not with a dict of values for the fields. And anyway, your code just initialises a Serializer without doing anything with it, so it wouldn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [this document](http://www.cdrf.co/3.9/rest_framework.generics/UpdateAPIView.html#update) to understand how these generic views work and where to best customise behavior. If you look at `update` you'll see it calls `get_object()` before using the `instance` returned to perform the partial update using the serializer. So it's best if you just move your code into `get_object()` so that the instance is already updated with your fields before it's partially updated with `data`.